# How to compare the character using strcmp without the compiler warning message?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   17 |             if(strcmp(string[i],string[j])<0)
      |                       ~~~~~~^~~
      |                             |
      |                             char
```

And my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    
    char string[100];
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    int length = strlen(string);
    int count= 0 ;
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        for(int j =i+1; j<length; j++) 
        {
            char temp; 
            if(strcmp(string[i],string[j])<0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, string[i]);
                strcpy(string[i], string[j]);
                strcpy(string[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    /* … code … */
}
```

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of the letter in the string and print them in the sorted order but it seems that while I try to … *(information missing)*

Comment: `string[i]` and `string[j]` are single characters. `if (string[i] < string[j])` may be what you want. Remember that `fgets` leaves the newline at the end of the input.

Comment: `strcmp` compares entire strings, not individual characters. Same about `strcpy`, it copies entire strings.

Comment: Consider changing the variable initialization char string[100]  to char letters[100]

Comment: With the loop `for(int j =i+1 ;j<length; j++)` you will include the string null-terminator.

Comment: And generally, if a function have the `str` prefix then it's dealing with *strings*.